# octave - many graphs in one window

Tags: graph, plot, octave

I am using octave.
How to add more than one graph in one window ?  I mean three independent graphs.
I tried to find it in documentation, but withou success.

PS What about title of each graph ?

Comment: Did you google [subplot](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Multiple-Plots-on-One-Page.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subplot is the way to go.  You can get handles to each individual graph

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Multiple-Plots-on-One-Page.html